# Kentico rename"Code name" in Widget or Webpart without losing data

Tags: kentico

I want to rename "Code name" in Widget or Webpart that I have created. After I rename Code name 'FAQItem' to 'FAQ' when I go to Page a content that I have insert into Page it lose.

Here message error "[Error loading the WebPart 'FAQItem' of type 'FAQItem']"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without manually updating all references of that widget on all pages it is used on.

There is an alternative to run a SQL query against the `CMS_Document` table and look in the `DocumentContent` field for `%yourCodeName%` and do a simple [SQL REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Here's some [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/widget-internals-and-api) regarding widgets and the API.

Comment: I have a similar question as the topic starter has but for the website code, what is the official way to do that for the existing website?

Comment: Are you asking how do you update your code to use a new code name?  I'd suggest a CTRL+F and do a search and replace.